# c++. valgrind outputs: Syscall param open(filename) points to unaddressable byte(s)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

i'm working on a little project which amongst other things parses some files.
when i check my project with valgrind i get this error:

`Syscall param open(filename) points to unaddressable byte(s)`

to my understanding (and reading) it means that im sending a memory that is not defined, null or was deleted but i cant figure out why...

this is engine.cpp. its constructor receives the "char** argv" variable from the console

```
//alot of includes and using namespace std.

Engine::Engine(char** args) {
    processConfFile(args[1]);
}

void Engine::processConfFile ( char* fileName) {
    string* fileContent = fileToString(fileName); //this line is specified at the stacktrace
    stringstream contentstream(*fileContent);
// parsing and stuff
    delete fileContent;
}

string* Engine::fileToString(const char* fileName) const{
    string* content = new string();
    ifstream ifs (fileName); // this line produces the error
    if (ifs) {
        content->assign((istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
        ifs.close();
    }
    else {
        //TODO logger error.
    }
    return content;
}
```

do you know what is causing the problem?
thx in advance.

P.S: the code is working fine. the file is read and parsed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

My first guess is that args[1] isn't well defined/allocated when you construct your `Engine`. What do you expect to have in **args? How are you calling your constructor? I'd guess something like `Engine(argv)` in main, but if you never checked to see if argc was larger than 1, you'd be passing an array with uninitialized memory and it'd choke when you finally tried to use it.

Comment: your guess is correct. it is called directly from main like u wrote, and as i said the program is running correctly so its obviously defined and not null. do u think that valgrind checks if i checked argc?

Comment: When you run the program are you passing any arguments to it? argv is an array of your command line arguments, argv[0] being the command name, and argv[1] being the first argument, etc. If you didn't pass any arguments, **argv won't be null, argv[0] will be populated, but argv[1] is going to be garbage - may not be null, but may not contain useful data.

Comment: my main is called with 4 arguments, which i send directly to the engine.

Comment: Hmmm... missed the ps about the code actually working. If you just stick a loop like `for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) cout << argv[i] << endl;` in your `main`, does valgrind complain about uninitialized values on that loop? Did you compile with any optimizations on?

Comment: i added this for in the main, valgrind doesn't complain about it.

Comment: not sure about optimization... didn't do anything myself but im using eclipse 4.2 and g++ compiler